# Getting error - "Failed to authenticate with the remote. Please ensure that Replit has access to this repository on GitHub." being a collaborator

Tags: authentication, github, replit

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD2kj.png)

**Description:** I am working a web development project with a team. We have created a Github repository and the owner has added me as a collaborator. I am using replit for writing the code.

**Error:** I have connected to github while creating the Replit project and it is fetching the details as well but when I am trying to synchronize or do the changes, I am getting this error.

**Doubt:** What can be the possible mitigation options??

I have tried exploring the permissions from the owner's side and searching documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this just now and I fixed this issue by creating a repository in my personal Github account (make sure the repository is set to public visibility), then copy the newly created repository url. In Replit's shell, set the new remote git url by typing:

```
git remote set-url origin <new url>
```

What I found to be the issue is that basically the error 'Getting error - "Failed to authenticate with the remote. Please ensure that Replit has access to this repository on GitHub." being a collaborator', is because the set repository for the replit project is automatically set to: https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-project-exercisetracker.git
if you import the freeCodeCamp project from replit directly.

You can always check the project's remote url by using:

```
git remote -v
```

Just to make sure that you are in your desired repository.

Took months to get an answer, but could still perhaps be helpful for anyone who are also working with freeCodeCamp replit projects in the future.